Is $\text{Id}-T$ always invertible when $\lim_{n\to\infty} T^n = 0$?
Let $T$ be a linear map on a normed vector space over the real numbers. I know that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} T^n = 0,
\end{align*}
i.e. applying $T$ "infinitely many times" results in the zero element.
Does this imply that $\text{Id} - T$ is invertible, where $\text{Id}$ is the identity map? I.e. that $\text{Id} - T$ is bijective and the inverse $(\text{Id} - T)^{-1}$ exists? This seems to be the case from the Neumann series, but I am not too familiar with functional analysis, so any help is greatly appreciated!
Edit: I made a mistake in the title which I have fixed. The text in my question is unchanged.

What if $T=I$? or $T$ is a rotation maps?

Title: No, take $T=0$. In the body, you consider a different operator, namely $Id-T$.

@DietrichBurde Sorry, I made a mistake in the title (fixed now). Do you know the answer to the question in the main text?

@MadhanKumar Sorry, I made a mistake in the title (fixed now). Do you know the answer to the question in the main text?

The operator is injective, but not surjective in general.

@Greaseddog Can you clarify whether you mean $\Vert T^n \Vert \rightarrow 0$ or $\Vert T^n x\Vert \rightarrow 0$ for all $x$? In the second case $I-T$ is certainly not surjective in general.

@geetha290krm Yes that is a mistake! Thanks for the remark, I'll edit my comment. Edit: cannot edit anymore, so I took it down since it's no longer relevant

@SeverinSchraven Thank you. I mean the second case. So you are saying the second case does not imply the first? But either way, I - T is at least injective (that is also useful to me)?

Injectivity is trivial since the kernel is ${0}$.

Injective: Let us first prove that $I-T$ is injective. For this we check that the kernel is trivial. Let $v$ be in the kernel of $I-T$, i.e. $(I-T)v=0$, then $v=Iv=Tv$. However, this cannot be as otherwise we would have $T^n v=v$ which contradicts the assumption that $T^n v \rightarrow 0$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$.
Not surjective: However, in general the map $I-T$ will not be surjective. Consider the map
$$ T: \ell^2(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow \ell^2(\mathbb{N}), (x_m)_{m\geq 1} \mapsto ((1-e^{-m})x_m)_{m\geq 1}. $$
This map is linear and
$$ T^n((x_m)_{m\geq 1}) = ((1-e^{-m})^n x_m)_{m\geq 1} $$
which readily implies that
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \Vert T^n((x_m)_{m\geq 1})\Vert = 0. $$
Indeed, we have for every $N\geq 1$
$$ \Vert T^n((x_m)_{m\geq 1})\Vert^2
\leq \sum_{m\geq N+1} \vert x_m \vert^2 + (1-e^{-N})^{2n}\sum_{m=1}^N \vert x_m \vert^2.  $$
Thus,
$$ \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Vert T^n((x_m)_{m\geq 1})\Vert^2
\leq \sum_{m\geq N+1} \vert x_m \vert^2. $$
Taking $N\rightarrow \infty$ yields the desired limit.
On the other hand, we have
$$ (I-T)((x_m)_{m\geq 1}) = (e^{-m} x_m)_{m\geq 1}. $$
Thus, the inverse map would need to map
$$ (I-T)^{-1}((1/m)_{m\geq}) = (e^m/m)_{m\geq 1}, $$
however, the later is not square summable. Thus, we get that $(1/m)_{m\geq 1}$ is not in the image of $I-T$.
Convergence in operator norm: Previously I have only assumed that $T^n \rightarrow 0$ in strong operator topology. On the other hand, if $T: X\rightarrow X$, $X$ a Banach space and $\Vert T^n \Vert \rightarrow 0$ (i.e. we have convergence in operator norm), then we get that $(I-T)$ is a bijection (just by using the Neumann series).
If we do not assume $X$ to complete, then also the convergence in operator norm is not going to safe us. Indeed, consider $c_{00}$ to be the space of real-valued sequences with only finitely many nonzero entries. Then the operator
$$ T: c_{00} \rightarrow c_{00}, (x_n)_{n\geq 1}\mapsto(\frac{x_{n+1}}{2})_{n\geq 1} $$
converges in operator norm to the zero operator. However, $(1, 0, 0, \dots)$ will not be in the image of $I-T$. Assume it was, then we would have
$$ (1, 0, 0, \dots ) = (I-T)(x_1, x_2, \dots) = (x_1, x_2-\frac{x_1}{2}, x_3-\frac{x_2}{2}, \dots). $$
Solving the equation coordinatewise we get $x_1=1$ and for $n\geq 2$
$$ 0 = x_n-\frac{x_{n-1}}{2} $$
which yields
$$ (x_1, x_2, \dots) = (2^{-n+1})_{n\geq 1} \notin c_{00}. $$

Interesting. In german Wikipedia, it says that the Neumann Series converges if $\lVert T^n \rVert < 1$ for some $n$.  Is that wrong? Or am I missing something?

@HyperbolicPDEfriend I hope it does not only say this in the German Wikipedia as it is indeed true. However, I am not assuming that $\Vert T^n \Vert<1$, I am only assuming that for all $x$ we have $\Vert T^n x \Vert \rightarrow 0$ which is much weaker (that is why I asked what exactly is meant in the comments below the post).

@HyperbolicPDEfriend What I meant to say is that I am only assuming that $T^n \rightarrow 0$ in the strong operator topology. For the Neumann series one would need to have convergence in the operator norm (in that case one gets that $(I-T)$ is invertible if the space in question is complete).

@HyperbolicPDEfriend Finally, even if we assume convergence in operator norm, then we would still need the space to be complete (otherwise, the Neumann series needs not to converge even for $\Vert T \Vert <1$).

Ah, you are right. I just did not read carefully. That is obviously a huge difference. Thank you!

@HyperbolicPDEfriend It was a good question. Made me add the details :)

I assume that the space is complete. If $\|T^n\|\to 0$ then $\|T^k\|<1$ for some $k>0.$ Then the operator $I-T^k$ is invertible, by applying the Neumann series. We have $$I-T^k=(I-T)(I+T+\ldots +T^{k-1})=(I+T+\ldots +T^{k-1})(I-T)$$ Thus the operator $$(I+T+\ldots +T^{k-1})(I-T^k)^{-1}$$ is the inverse of $I-T.
$ More explicitly $$(I-T)^{-1}=(I+T+\ldots +T^{k-1})\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^{kn}$$ Thus $$\|(I-T)^{-1}\|\le (1+\|T\|+\ldots+\|T\|^{k-1})\sum_{n=0}^\infty \\ = \|T^k\|^n= {1+\|T\|+\ldots+\|T\|^{k-1}\over 1-\|T^k\|}$$
